# OpenCV 32-bit image out of bounds error?

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm sure I'm going to smack myself when I find out what I'm doing wrong here, but why is this causing an exception to be thrown in OpenCV 2.4.6?

```
cv::Mat img(240, 320, CV_8UC4);
img.at<uint32_t>(180, 180) = 0x00000000;
```

The exception is thrown by second line where the pixel value is set. It's a four channel image and I'm accessing it well within bounds. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your mat is of type CV_8UC4, so, that's 4 channels á 8 bytes.

the correct access to it would be :

```
img.at<cv::Vec4b>(180,180) = cv::Vec4b(0,0,0,0);
```

Comment: Yep, I actually just found this myself. I'm unclear as to why it doesn't work with a `uint32_t` type, but it does work this way, so it's a solution. Thanks!